# Indexing elements from a batch tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

Say, I have a batch of images in PyTorch. For each image, I also have a pixel location say `(x, y)`. The pixel value can be read using `img[x, y]` for one image. I am trying to read pixel value for each image in the batch. Please see below the code snippet:

```
import torch

# create tensors to represent random images in torch format
img_1 = torch.rand(1, 200, 300)
img_2 = torch.rand(1, 200, 300)
img_3 = torch.rand(1, 200, 300)
img_4 = torch.rand(1, 200, 300)

# for each image, x-y value are know, so creating a tuple
img1_xy = (0, 10, 70)
img2_xy = (0, 40, 20)
img3_xy = (0, 30, 50)
img4_xy = (0, 80, 60)

# this is what I am doing right now
imgs = [img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4]
imgs_xy = [img1_xy, img2_xy, img3_xy, img4_xy]
x = [img[xy] for img, xy in zip(imgs, imgs_xy)]
x = torch.as_tensor(x)
```

## My Concerns and Questions

1. In each image, the pixel location i.e., `(x, y)` is know. However, I have to create a tuple with one more element, i.e., 0 to make sure that tuple matches the shape of image. Any elegant way?
2. Instead of using `tuple`, can't we use tensor and then get the pixel values?
3. All images can be concatenated to make a batch as `img_batch = torch.cat((img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4))`. But what about tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatanate the images to form a  `(4, 200, 300)` shaped stacked tensor. Then, we can index into this with the known `(x, y)` pairs for each image as follows: we need `[0, x1, y1]` for first image, `[1, x2, y2]` for second image, `[2, x3, y3]` for third image and so on. These can be achieved with "fancy indexing":

```
# stacking as you did
>>> stacked_imgs = torch.cat(imgs)
>>> stacked_imgs.shape
(4, 200, 300)

# no need for 0s in front
>>> imgs_xy = [(10, 70), (40, 20), (30, 50), (80, 60)]

# need xs together and ys together: take transpose of `imgs_xy`
>>> inds_x, inds_y = torch.tensor(imgs_xy).T

>>> inds_x
tensor([10, 40, 30, 80])

>>> inds_y
tensor([70, 20, 50, 60])

# now we index into the batch
>>> num_imgs = len(imgs)
>>> result = stacked_imgs[range(num_imgs), inds_x, inds_y]
>>> result
tensor([0.5359, 0.4863, 0.6942, 0.6071])
```

We can check the result:

```
>>> torch.tensor([img[0, x, y] for img, (x, y) in zip(imgs, imgs_xy)])

tensor([0.5359, 0.4863, 0.6942, 0.6071])
```

---

To answer your questions:

*1:* Since we stacked the images, that issue is mitigated and we use `range(4)` to index into each individual image instead.

*2:* Yes, we indeed turn `x, y` positions into tensors.

*3:* We directly index with them after they are separated into tensors.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. However, I just realized that PyTorch creating the batch of the shape `(4, 1, 200, 300)`, So should 0 be inserted as `stacked_imgs[range(num_imgs), 0, inds_x, inds_y]`? Or an elegant way?

Comment: hi @RaviJoshi, that's interesting but I'm unable to produce. Still, you can `squeeze` the batch to get rid of that 1 in the shape altogether: `stacked_imgs = stacked_imgs.squeeze()`.